# Excel - Is there a way to tell a cell to use a certain function based on the first letter of a another cell?

Tags: excel

I am creating a Product Decoder for a project.

Lets say, Our product can have a code such as "ABCDE" OR a code like "BCDEF".

ABCDE has a table of data that I use to decode using a lookup. For example AB can decode into "Potato" and CDE can decode into "Chip". So any combination with AB can be Potato "Anything else".

BCDER, BC can decode into "Veggie" so DER can code into "Chip".

I also use the 1/search method to take placements for the decode. Example =IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/SEARCH($E$19:$E$23,N18),$E$19:$E$23), "")

I concatenate all the decodes using =S2&" "&T2&" "&U2&" "&V2

Question is...if we are getting a huge amount of product code coming that I want to decode into one single column... How do I tell excel to use this table of data for ABCDE if product starts with "A", if not, use table of data that correlates to BCDER when product starts with "B".

Edit 1:

[Here is my table, right side is where i look up the Part Number column N"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpQeh.png)

As you can see on column "W" I concatenate the date is Look up from columns O~V.
Column O Function: =IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/SEARCH($C$1:$C$7,N2),$C$1:$C$7), "")

On column N, I have two parts. One that starts with M and one that starts with K which is pretty standard.

[Image two is me trying to use the IF Left but, it doesn't really work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IK0ZN.png)
=IF(LEFT(AA4,10) = "M ", W2, W18)

So How can I tell my excel page to use Table A1:A12 if part starts with "M*" and vice versa?

Let me know if this is confusing, I will do my best to clear things up.

Comment: Use `IF` and `LEFT`?

Comment: Can you actually show sample data and expected results?

Comment: Hello, Let me revise some data because it is confidential. I will edit my post shortly! Thank you for responding. 

BigBen, I tried using IF and Left but it will only look for exact match..let me put more description on my post!

Comment: Your post is very confusing. I've tried to answer your question, however, your reference photos have no column or row labels that reference back to your post. Also, your post switches between looking up values in columns A, C, and E. Each lookup is of the same type, so really, you could simplify the problem down to one lookup and extrapolate from there. That would also allow you to put your data in text form, which is the recommended format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First, a possible correction**

I *think* this function does not give you what you say it does:

```
= IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/SEARCH($E$19:$E$23,N18),$E$19:$E$23), "")
```

You might mean:

```
= IFERROR( LOOKUP( 2, 1/SEARCH( $E$19:$E$23, N18 ), $F$19:$F$23 ), "" )
```

Because you want to look up the value in column E and return the value in column F. If that's not true, then skip the rest of this answer.

**Now the solution**

What you're trying to do is change the lookup array if the part number starts with a different letter. So, the `IF( LEFT(` combo mentioned by @BigBen should be used to modify the lookup array. I think it would look like this:

```
= IFERROR( LOOKUP( 2
                  ,1/SEARCH( IF( LEFT( AA4, 1 ) = "M"
                                ,$C$2:$C$12
                                ,$C$19:$C$23 )
                            ,N2 )
                  ,IF( LEFT( AA4, 1 ) = "M"
                      ,$D$2:$D$12
                      ,$D$19:$D$23 )
                 )
          ,"")
```

Comment: StoneGiant, thank you so much! I will work to have a more clear and concise wording next time. your solution made this so much more easier and implied so many steps.Thank you!!!

Comment: Glad it helped.